# How to set default access as Reporter instead of Guest in Gitlab?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I have projects in Gitlab (visibility is Internal).There is an option for any user (email ending with company email) to register. But once they register, they get only Guest access and I have to manually change their access to Reporter. How do we change this default to Reporter access instead of Guest?

Kindly let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a selfhosted instance, or are we talking about GitLab.com with SSO?

Comment: This is a self-hosted instance (and Gitlab Community Edition)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, this Gitlab issue may be related: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/205378. They've requested the ability to change the default user permission so that any logged in user can push to non-protected branches. The Gitlab team stated some concerns over opening that up and proposed allowing Guest users to push to non-protected branches. The issue is still open however, so it seems it's still in progress.

If you're a paid customer (one of the paid self-hosted tiers) talking to the sales team is a good way to give the issue some priority. Otherwise upvoting the issue may help.